# Pandas Cumulative on sign concept

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column like, it has lot of values, some +ve and some -ve

```
 V
-1
-4
-3
-2
+1
+2
+1
+5
-3
-1
+1
+4
-5
-2
-4
+4
+6
```

I want to create another column, which has cumulative such that

if current position value is not of same sign of previous one then cumulative for current position is current value + previous value

If current position value is of same sign as previous one then cumulative of current position is cumulative of previous position + current value

value is V and cumulative is Cumulative as shown

```
V   Cumulative
-1  -1
-4  -5
-3  -8
-2  -10
+1  -1
+2  +1
+1  +2
+5  +7
-3  +2
-1  +1
+1  +0
+4  +4
-5  -1
-2  -3
-4  -7
+4  +0
+6  +6
```

As you can see the sign direction changes, it results in cumulative changes as a reset concept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question :-),I break down the steps

```
# restore the value change(positive to negative) in and assign the group number , in the group you will only see all positive or negative. 
df['g']=df.gt(0).diff().ne(0).cumsum()
# find the last value of the group
DF=df.groupby('g').last() 
# shift the value to the next group , cause you need to carry save the value change
DF.index=DF.index+1
# combine the previous 
df.groupby('g').V.cumsum()+df.g.map(DF.V).fillna(0) 

Out[407]: 
0     -1.0
1     -5.0
2     -8.0
3    -10.0
4     -1.0
5      1.0
6      2.0
7      7.0
8      2.0
9      1.0
10     0.0
11     4.0
12    -1.0
13    -3.0
14    -7.0
15     0.0
16     6.0
dtype: float64
```

After assign the new column

```
df['cumlative']=df.groupby('g').V.cumsum()+df.g.map(DF.V).fillna(0)
df
Out[409]: 
    V  g  cumlative
0  -1  1       -1.0
1  -4  1       -5.0
2  -3  1       -8.0
3  -2  1      -10.0
4   1  2       -1.0
5   2  2        1.0
6   1  2        2.0
7   5  2        7.0
8  -3  3        2.0
9  -1  3        1.0
10  1  4        0.0
11  4  4        4.0
12 -5  5       -1.0
13 -2  5       -3.0
14 -4  5       -7.0
15  4  6        0.0
16  6  6        6.0
```

Comment: You are really good at this kind of answers. This one `df.gt(0).diff().ne(0).cumsum()`
alone deserves more votes

Comment: @Bharath Maybe I just think why they want and think about  the back end mechanism

Comment: I still need more expertise. Though glad I understood your solution. Next time I would think your way.

Comment: @Wen you are too good. If you can add some comments to explain steps, it would be very helpful

Comment: @Tahseen Add some explanation, your back end mechanism, is split the value by pos and neg, but you also need to carry over the previous change in the next group

Comment: @Wen, very nice solution and better yet comments :-D

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** Define variables and helper functions

```
sum_p = 0 # sum previous
value_p = 0 # value previous
sign_p = "-"

def sign(x):
    return("+" if x>0 else "-")

df = pd.DataFrame({"V": df.V, "Cumulative":0}, columns = ["V","Cumulative"])
```

**Step 2.** Calculate Cumulative

```
for i in df.iterrows():
    if sign(i[1][0]) == sign_p:
        df.iloc[i[0],1] = sum_p + i[1][0]
    else:
        df.iloc[i[0],1] = value_p + i[1][0]
    sum_p = i[1][1]
    value_p = i[1][0]
    sign_p = sign(i[1][0])

df
    V   Cumulative
0   -1  -1
1   -4  -5
2   -3  -8
3   -2  -10
4   1   -1
5   2   1
6   1   2
7   5   7
8   -3  2
9   -1  1
10  1   0
11  4   4
12  -5  -1
13  -2  -3
14  -4  -7
15  4   0
16  6   6
```

Comment: Thanks. But programmatically, even I coded. I wanted it to be Pandas way